# Dash data table add a column on user input with predefined values

Tags: python, datatable, plotly-dash

I have a simple dash app containing a data table.Two user inputs make it possible to add a row or a column. Juste like when I add a row I get default values (here 0 hours) for every column, I would also like to have default values for all rows when adding a new column. Here is the code:

```
import pathlib as pl
import dash
from dash import dash_table
from dash.dash_table.Format import Format, Scheme, Sign, Symbol
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

table_header_style = {
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(2,21,70)",
    "color": "white",
    "textAlign": "center",
}


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.title = "Trial"
server = app.server

APP_PATH = str(pl.Path(__file__).parent.resolve())

list_rows = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
tasks = ['task' + str(i) for i in range(5)]
data = {task:[0 for i in range(len(list_rows))] for task in tasks}

app.layout = html.Div(
    className="",
    children=[
        html.Div(
            # className="container",
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    # className="row",
                    style={},
                    children=[
                        html.Div(
                            # className="four columns pkcalc-settings",
                            children=[
                                html.P(["Study Design"]),
                                html.Div(
                                    [
                                        html.Label(
                                            [
                                                dcc.Input(
                                                    id="new-row",
                                                    placeholder="Row to be added...",
                                                    type="text",
                                                    debounce=True,
                                                    maxLength=20,
                                                    style={
                                                        'width':'66%',
                                                        'margin-left': '5px'
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                                html.Button(
                                                    'Add', 
                                                    id='add-row-button', 
                                                    n_clicks=0,
                                                    style={
                                                        'font-size': '10px', 
                                                        'width': '140px', 
                                                        'display': 'inline-block', 
                                                        'margin-bottom': '5px', 
                                                        'margin-right': '5px',
                                                        'margin-left': '5px', 
                                                        'height':'38px', 
                                                        'verticalAlign': 'top'
                                                        }
                                                    ),
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        html.Label(
                                            [
                                                dcc.Input(
                                                    id="new-task",
                                                    placeholder="Task to be added...",
                                                    type="text",
                                                    debounce=True,
                                                    maxLength=50,
                                                    style={'width':'66%'}
                                                ),
                                                html.Button(
                                                    'Add', 
                                                    id='add-task-button', 
                                                    n_clicks=0,
                                                    style={
                                                        'font-size': '10px', 
                                                        'width': '140px', 
                                                        'display': 'inline-block', 
                                                        'margin-bottom': '5px', 
                                                        'margin-right': '5px',
                                                        'margin-left': '5px', 
                                                        'height':'38px', 
                                                        'verticalAlign': 'top'
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        html.Div(
                            # className="eight columns pkcalc-data-table",
                            children=[
                                dash_table.DataTable(
                                    id='table',
                                    columns=(
                                        [{
                                            'id': 'name', 
                                            'name': 'Name',
                                            'type': 'text',
                                            'deletable': True,
                                            'renamable': True,
                                        }] +
                                        [{
                                            'id': task, 
                                            'name': task,
                                            'type': 'numeric',
                                            'deletable': True,
                                            'renamable': True,
                                            'format': Format(
                                                precision=0,
                                                scheme=Scheme.fixed,
                                                symbol=Symbol.yes,
                                                symbol_suffix='h'
                                            ),
                                        } for task in tasks]
                                    ),
                                    data=[dict(name=i, **{task: 0 for task in tasks}) for i in list_rows],
                                    editable=True,
                                    style_header=table_header_style,
                                    active_cell={"row": 0, "column": 0},
                                    selected_cells=[{"row": 0, "column": 0}],
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)



# Callback to add column
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='columns'),
    Input(component_id='add-task-button', component_property='n_clicks'),
    State(component_id='new-task', component_property='value'),
    State(component_id='table', component_property='columns'),)
def update_columns(n_clicks, new_task, existing_tasks):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        existing_tasks.append({
            'id': new_task, 'name': new_task,
            'renamable': True, 'deletable': True
        })
    return existing_tasks

# Callback to add row
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='data'),
    Input(component_id='add-row-button', component_property='n_clicks'),
    State(component_id='new-row', component_property='value'),
    State(component_id='table', component_property='columns'),
    State(component_id='table', component_property='data'))
def update_rows(n_clicks, new_row, columns, rows):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append(
            {
                'name': new_row,
                **{column['id']: 0 for column in columns[1:]}
            }
        )
    return rows


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, the duplicate callback outputs is an issue you cannot work around since both callbacks need to update `table.data`, so combining these two into one callback function is the right solution.

However, you could refactor a bit to use specific functions for each action in order to reduce the size of the callback :

```py
def add_column(new_task, columns, data):
    columns.append({
        'id': new_task,
        'name': new_task,
        'type': 'numeric',
        'deletable': True,
        'renamable': True,
        'format': Format(
            precision=0,
            scheme=Scheme.fixed,
            symbol=Symbol.yes,
            symbol_suffix='h'
        )
    })

    for row in data:
        row[new_task] = 0

    return columns, data


def add_row(new_row, columns, data):
    data.append(
        {
            'name': new_row,
            **{column['id']: 0 for column in columns[1:]}
        }
    )
    return data
```

Also note that you can distinguish which component/property pair has triggered the callback by using [`dash.callback_context`](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#determining-which-input-has-fired-with-dash.callback_context), which simplify things :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='columns'),
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='data'),
    Input(component_id='add-row-button', component_property='n_clicks'),
    Input(component_id='add-task-button', component_property='n_clicks'),
    State(component_id='new-row', component_property='value'),
    State(component_id='new-task', component_property='value'),
    State(component_id='table', component_property='columns'),
    State(component_id='table', component_property='data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_table(nc_row, nc_task, new_row, new_task, columns, data):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    id, prop = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')

    if id == 'add-row-button':
        columns, data = add_row(new_row, columns, data)
    elif id == 'add-task-button':
        data = add_column(new_task, columns, data)

    return columns, data
```

---

[EDIT] : Actually there exists a workaround, but it requires to install  [dash-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/dash-extensions/) :

The package provides a proxy component and something called a [`MultiplexerTransform`](https://www.dash-extensions.com/pages/transforms/multiplexer-transform), which can be used to make possible for multiple callbacks to target the same output (note that it will chain/merge the callbacks under the hood).

Comment: Thank you very much @EricLavault! Had to invert the assignments of the `add_row` and `add_column` in the callback like so: `data = add_row(new_row, columns, data)` and `columns, data = add_column(new_task, columns, data)`. It works like a charm and looks cleaner thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way using one callback only to add a column or a row. It's not the prettiest but it works. If anyone has a better way, allowing to keep the two callbacks separated I would appreciate it.

Here is the code:

```
import pathlib as pl
import dash
from dash import dash_table
from dash.dash_table.Format import Format, Scheme, Sign, Symbol
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

table_header_style = {
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(2,21,70)",
    "color": "white",
    "textAlign": "center",
}


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.title = "Trial"
server = app.server

APP_PATH = str(pl.Path(__file__).parent.resolve())

list_rows = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
tasks = ['task' + str(i) for i in range(5)]
data = {task:[0 for i in range(len(list_rows))] for task in tasks}

app.layout = html.Div(
    className="",
    children=[
        html.Div(
            # className="container",
            children=[
                dcc.Store(id='n_clicks-column', data=0),
                dcc.Store(id='n_clicks-row', data=0),
                html.Div(
                    # className="row",
                    style={},
                    children=[
                        html.Div(
                            # className="four columns pkcalc-settings",
                            children=[
                                html.P(["Study Design"]),
                                html.Div(
                                    [
                                        html.Label(
                                            [
                                                dcc.Input(
                                                    id="new-row",
                                                    placeholder="Row to be added...",
                                                    type="text",
                                                    debounce=True,
                                                    maxLength=20,
                                                    style={
                                                        'width':'66%',
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                                html.Button(
                                                    'Add', 
                                                    id='add-row-button', 
                                                    n_clicks=0,
                                                    style={
                                                        'font-size': '10px', 
                                                        'width': '140px', 
                                                        'display': 'inline-block', 
                                                        'margin-bottom': '5px', 
                                                        'margin-right': '5px',
                                                        'margin-left': '5px', 
                                                        'height':'38px', 
                                                        'verticalAlign': 'top'
                                                        }
                                                    ),
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        html.Label(
                                            [
                                                dcc.Input(
                                                    id="new-task",
                                                    placeholder="Task to be added...",
                                                    type="text",
                                                    debounce=True,
                                                    maxLength=50,
                                                    style={'width':'66%'}
                                                ),
                                                html.Button(
                                                    'Add', 
                                                    id='add-task-button', 
                                                    n_clicks=0,
                                                    style={
                                                        'font-size': '10px', 
                                                        'width': '140px', 
                                                        'display': 'inline-block', 
                                                        'margin-bottom': '5px', 
                                                        'margin-right': '5px',
                                                        'margin-left': '5px', 
                                                        'height':'38px', 
                                                        'verticalAlign': 'top'
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        html.Div(
                            # className="eight columns pkcalc-data-table",
                            children=[
                                dash_table.DataTable(
                                    id='table',
                                    columns=(
                                        [{
                                            'id': 'name', 
                                            'name': 'Name',
                                            'type': 'text',
                                            'deletable': True,
                                            'renamable': True,
                                        }] +
                                        [{
                                            'id': task, 
                                            'name': task,
                                            'type': 'numeric',
                                            'deletable': True,
                                            'renamable': True,
                                            'format': Format(
                                                precision=0,
                                                scheme=Scheme.fixed,
                                                symbol=Symbol.yes,
                                                symbol_suffix='h'
                                            ),
                                        } for task in tasks]
                                    ),
                                    data=[dict(name=i, **{task: 0 for task in tasks}) for i in list_rows],
                                    editable=True,
                                    style_header=table_header_style,
                                    active_cell={"row": 0, "column": 0},
                                    selected_cells=[{"row": 0, "column": 0}],
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='columns'),
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='data'),
    Output(component_id='n_clicks-column', component_property='data'),
    Output(component_id='n_clicks-row', component_property='data'),
    Input(component_id='add-task-button', component_property='n_clicks'),
    Input(component_id='add-row-button', component_property='n_clicks'),
    State(component_id='new-task', component_property='value'),
    State(component_id='new-row', component_property='value'),
    State(component_id='table', component_property='columns'),
    State(component_id='table', component_property='data'),
    State(component_id='n_clicks-column', component_property='data'),
    State(component_id='n_clicks-row', component_property='data')
    )
def update_table(n_clicks_column, n_clicks_row, new_task, new_row, columns, table_data, stored_n_clicks_column, stored_n_clicks_row):
    
    if n_clicks_column > stored_n_clicks_column:
        columns.append({
            'id': new_task, 
            'name': new_task,
            'type': 'numeric',
            'renamable': True, 
            'deletable': True,
            'format': Format(
                precision=0,
                scheme=Scheme.fixed,
                symbol=Symbol.yes,
                symbol_suffix='h'
            ),
        })

        for row_dict in table_data:
            row_dict[new_task] = 0

        stored_n_clicks_column += 1

    if n_clicks_row > stored_n_clicks_row:
        table_data.append(
            {
                'name': new_row,
                **{column['id']: 0 for column in columns[1:]}
            }
        )

        stored_n_clicks_row += 1
    

    return columns, table_data, stored_n_clicks_column, stored_n_clicks_row

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I had to add 2 `dcc.Store` to keep in memory the number of time each button has been clicked. Then I had to gather the 2 callbacks into one in order to modify the `'data'` and `'columns'` properties of the data table at once.

I tried keeping the two callbacks separated but in order to add default values to the new column, the only way I found was to modify both the `'data'` and `'columns'` properties in the add column callback. And dash doesn't allow to have 2 callbacks modifying the same element, here the `'data'` property that was also being updated in the callback to add a row.